# Can passing context to static methods cause memory leaks in Android?

Tags: c#, android, memory-leaks, xamarin.android

I have a lot of static helper methods in my project and I often pass context to them as an argument. Here are two examples

```
private static bool SaveSetupDetails(Context context, string sftpAddress, string sftpUserName, string sftpPassword)
{
    try
    {
        using (ISharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(context))
        using (ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = settings.Edit())
        {
            editor.PutString("VePSFTPAddr", sftpAddress);
            editor.PutString("VePSFTPUser", sftpUserName);
            editor.PutString("VePSFTPPass", sftpPassword);

            editor.Commit();
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Debug("SomeTag", "SomeActivity - SaveSetupDetails threw an exception: " + e.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Second example

```
public static bool IsCallActive(Context context)
{
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
    if (manager.Mode == Mode.InCall)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am wondering if passing the context like this can cause the static method to hold on to it's reference and cause a memory leak. Or does it get de-referenced after the method is done executing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi @Ali Zahid if you are passing context in parameters and using like the above two methods then it will get de-referenced because you haven't stored its object using static keyword in the class. Only those objects will be saved in the memory in which we have applied static keyword in front of the class name while initializing. for example

```
static int a = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unregistered in references in onDestroy() safely and avoiding memory leaks.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
//unregister your references.
}
```

:)